# Editing bootstrap template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to edit this template here:

http://startbootstrap.com/templates/grayscale/

What I am trying to do is reduce the amount of space at the top and bottom of the section that says "About Grayscale", and also at the bottom where it says contact start bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look for this:

```
.content-section {
  padding-top: 250px;
}
```

in grayscale.css

and reduce it. This is applied to each content section, so reducing it will also reduce the space at the bottom